# Is there an equivalent argument to names_ptypes in reshape?

Tags: r, tidyr

In the base function of `reshape`, with direction set to `"long"`, is there another argument that will have the same effect as `names_ptypes` of `tidyr::pivot_longer`?

Comment: No. reshape casts all datatype to character in case they dont match and then combines. On the other hand, pivot_longer wont allow you to combine data of different types hence the need for those arguments

Comment: why do you need one?